# Remove fullstop, commas, quotation from list in Python

Tags: python-2.7, word-frequency

I have a python code for word frequency count from a text file. The problem with the program is that it takes fullstop into account hence altering the count. For counting word i've used a sorted list of words. I tried to remove the fullstop using

```
 words = open(f, 'r').read().lower().split()  
 uniqueword = sorted(set(words))
 uniqueword = uniqueword.replace(".","")
```

but i get error as

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It isn’t clear exactly what problem you’re having.  Are you finding that you have words with trailing punctuation?  Or are you instead finding that there are punctuation characters in your list of "words"?

Comment: The output i get :


   `Words    Count

    blondes  4

    blondes. 2`


both are same word, the only difference is one comes somewhere in middle of the sentence, whereas the other comes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can process the words before you make the `set`, using a list comprehension:

```
words = [word.replace(".", "") for word in words]
```

You could also remove them after (`uniquewords = [word.replace...]`), but then you will reintroduce duplicates.

Note that if you want to count these words, a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) may be more useful:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off with

```
words = re.findall(r'\w+', open(f, 'r').read().lower())
```

which will grab all the strings composed of one or more “word characters” and will ignore punctuation and whitespace.